# AngularJS Scroll to ID using routeParams

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, routes, angularjs-routing

I'm making a single page app, that has subpages.

The idea is, I have urls e.g home, about and contact.
Each page then has multiple blocks.

The blocks are set a minimum height, when page loads. The minimum height is the window height. This is dynamic, so when you resize, the minimum height will be reset.

Currently, the routes are #/home/:blockId

When someone goes to http://www.test.com/#/home/page-17, the app should scroll down to that block.

My current code works, but the top position I am returned is the previous position before having the minimum height set.

If I'm not being clear, please feel free to ask for more detail. Thanks

See jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7nc9q/5/

**Javascript:**

```
var app = angular.module('siteApp', []);

app.controller( 'appController', function( $scope ) {
  //Main login here
});
app.controller( 'routeController', function( $scope, $routeParams ) {
  /* 
    Scroll to element ID
  */
  $scope.scrollTo = function(selector){
    if(jQuery('#' + selector).length == 1){
      console.log(jQuery('#' + selector).position().top);
      jQuery('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop:  jQuery('#' + selector).position().top
      });
    };
  }
  if(typeof $routeParams.page !== 'undefined' && $routeParams.page.length > 0){
    $scope.scrollTo($routeParams.page);
  }
});
app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/home/:page', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
        controller: 'routeController'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home/'
      });
}]);

app.directive('resize', function ($window) {
  return function (scope, element) {
      var w = angular.element($window);

      scope.getWindowDimensions = function () {
          return { height: w.height() };
      };

      scope.$watch(scope.getWindowDimensions, function (dimensions) {
          scope.windowHeight = dimensions.height;

          scope.style = function () {
              return { 
                  'min-height': scope.windowHeight + 'px'
              };
          };

      }, true);

      w.bind('resize', function () {
          scope.$apply();
      });
  }
});
```

**index.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="siteApp" ng-controller="appController">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="view" ng-view></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**templates/home.html**

```
<div class="page" id="page-17" >
    <div class="page-inner" ng-style="style()" resize></div>
</div>
<div class="page" id="page-18">
    <div class="page-inner" ng-style="style()" resize></div>
</div>
<div class="page" id="page-19">
    <div class="page-inner" ng-style="style()" resize></div>
</div>
<div class="page" id="page-20">
    <div class="page-inner" ng-style="style()" resize></div>
</div>
```

**Page layout example:**

[image]

Comment: Can you put an example on jsfiddle or plnkr ? Also, is there any difference in how it works if you use offset().top rather than position().top ?

Comment: Hi, I've tried offset, not luck there. Here is a jsfiddle as requested. http://jsfiddle.net/7nc9q/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be the scrollTo function is being run before the min-height is fully set. The resize seems like a red herring to me, as the problem happens even without any resizing.

To fix it,  run scrollTo wrapped in a $timeout instead (even just 1ms). That will force the DOM updates to be fully applied first, and it should then work correctly. That is, change it  from:

```
$scope.scrollTo($routeParams.page);
```

to:

```
$timeout(function() { $scope.scrollTo($routeParams.page) }, 1);
```

Working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/7nc9q/6/

BTW angular controllers are not supposed to have any references to the DOM or jQuery selectors in them, references to the DOM are only supposed to be in directives.

Comment: Great, thanks. First time using angular, will fix the controller issue and start using directives.

Answer (score 2):

There is an inbuilt property of angular **$anchorScroll** make sure you include in your controller

```
  $scope.anchorScroll = function()
            {
                $location.hash('compose-message');

                $anchorScroll();
            }
```

for more info check the documentaion: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll

only problem is: it updates the url first and then do the desired action normally, Use the following code to avoid it:

```
  $scope.anchorScroll = function()
                {
    var old = $location.hash();
                    $location.hash('compose-message');
                    $anchorScroll();
                    $location.hash(old);
}
```